# how to start node js project in a EC2 AWS instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am completely new to node js , I am trying to set it up in EC2 AWS.I tried using the command "npm start"  but nothing has happened

below is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "sample",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "ejs": "~2.6.1",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "pm2": "^5.1.2"
  }
}bouldercef$ npm start
```

after running npm start the below lines appear ,but not able to see the site

> boulder@0.0.0 start /home/ubuntu/bouldercef

> node ./bin/www

[image: in bound rules]
[image: out bound rules]

Comment: Are you able to run this app on your developer machine? What do you do to run it there? Also, one option for running Node.js in production (if that's what you're attempting to do here) is to use pm2 and nginx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your site is running properly in your machine, and if you have node/npm installed in your EC2 instance and you are not receiving any errors, looks like your project is running without issues.

So the problem can be  that you are not connect to your site using HTTP.

Take a look on the security group attached with your instance to check if you allow users to connect on HTTP (80) or HTTPS (443).

To more information of how to make these ports available for your users check [How do I allow my users to connect on HTTP (80) or HTTPS (443)?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-http-https-ec2/)

Comment: added screen shots of i-bound and out-bound rules please help here

Comment: @SivaPerumal can you share the code for starting the project, which port are you using?

Comment: yes the port was wrong in the inbound rules, it should be 3000 thanks !!!!!!